# StorangeReference firebase storage not working

Tags: flutter, dart

void uploadStatusImage() async {
if (validateAndSave()) {
final StorageReference postImageRef =
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");

```
  var timeKey = new DateTime.now();

  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
      postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);

  var ImageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownLoadURL();
  var url = ImageUrl.toString();

  print("Image Url =" + url);

  goToHomePage();

  saveToDabase(url);

}
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHl4A.png)

Comment: Please fix your code sample and provide more context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Storage reference like this.

```
Reference postImageRef  = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");
```